# Displaying multiple UICollectionViewCells via enum?

Tags: swift, xcode, enums, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have an iOS app, written in swift. It's a social platform where the users can post 9 different types of posts (text, image, video, link, audio, poll, chat, etc). I set those using an `enum`

```
enum PostType: String {

    case image = "image"
    case gif = "gif"
    case video = "video"
    case text = "text"
    case link = "link"
    case audio = "audio"
    case poll = "poll"
    case chat = "chat"
    case quote = "quote"
}
```

I'm utilising `FirebaseDatabase` to store the data. In the `DashboardViewController` I query the database and get the posts in an array along with the corresponding users, ready to be displayed.

```
func loadPosts() {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        Api.Feed.observeFeedPosts(withUserId: Api.Users.CURRENT_USER!.uid) {
            post in
            guard let userId = post.userUid else { return }
            self.fetchUser(uid: userId, completed: {
                self.posts.insert(post, at: 0)
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        Api.Feed.observeFeedRemoved(withUserId: Api.Users.CURRENT_USER!.uid) { (post) in

            self.posts = self.posts.filter { $0.id != post.id } // removed all array elements matching the key
            self.users = self.users.filter { $0.id != post.userUid }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void ) {
        Api.Users.observeUsersShort(withId: uid) {
            user in
            self.users.insert(user, at: 0)
            completed()
        }
    }
```

Whenever the user creates a new post, it stores `PostType.text.rawValue` (for example, it gives "text" String) on the database to differentiate between them (either video, photo, text, etc). Now, I have to use the `PostType` enum to figure out what the post type is and display the corresponding `UICollectionViewCell`. Now, if its a single cell, it's easy. I can do this and it works:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellName.postTextCVC, for: indexPath) as! PostTextCVC
    let user = users[indexPath.row]
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegatePostTextCVC = self
    cell.user = user
    cell.dashboardVC = self
    cell.post = post
    return cell
}
```

The problem is, how to use the `enum` to display the appropriate cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a variable `PostType` variable in your `Post` class. In `cellForItemAt` check post type of the post and dequeue respective cell.

Something like this.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    let type: PostType = post.type // Get the post type eg. text, image etc.

    switch type {
    case .text:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellName.postTextCVC, for: indexPath) as! PostTextCVC
          let user = users[indexPath.row]
          cell.delegatePostTextCVC = self
          cell.user = user
          cell.dashboardVC = self
          cell.post = post
        return cell
    case .image:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellName.postImageCVC, for: indexPath) as! PostImageCVC
        return cell
    case .video:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellName.postTextCVC, for: indexPath) as! PostVideoCVC
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

If you are using separate nib files for each collection view cell, make sure you register all possible nibs with collection view like this.

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "PostTextCVC", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CellName.postTextCVC)
```

Comment: `post.type` returns `nil` and it crashes and I cannot figure out why. And it shouldn't return `nil`, I see the value is set in the database.

Comment: that's completely different problem, better ask different question with details.